# C: Convert string to number when the value is arbitrarily large

Tags: c

As far as I can tell, in C all the numeric types have a fixed upper limit.  Therefore, to convert a string to a number, you have to know how big the number could possibly be.

Is there any way to convert strings to numbers *without* placing any kind of limit on the size of the numbers?  In case it matters, the numbers I care about are negative.

Comment: max int = 2^32... does that count as assuming size

Comment: Add what you did not get to work. As it is, this is asking for ready-made code -- "too broad".

Comment: Do you mean truly arbitrary precision here? For example, are you looking to convert negative numbers with 100+ decimal digits to binary representation?

Comment: Please specify input type and output type.

Comment: Input type will be integer and output might be string

Comment: @Steve : we can get the size of integer using sizeof() instead of assuming it as 2 bytes or 4 bytes.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without assuming an integer size , maybe you can pick the largest int size (64 bits with int64_t) and then work on it

Comment: "I know that this question will fetch me negative points" -- alternatively, update the question according to the suggestions in the comments...

Comment: If "Input type will be integer" does not that imply the input is `int` or `long` or some specified type?  Looks easy to create `void kadina_int_to_binary(int input, char *dest)`.  Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @kadina I've reformulated your question to make it clearer what you're asking.  If I have misunderstood what you wanted to know, please don't hesitate to revert -- but then please clarify it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core C language only supports integers of a definite size.  The stock facility for converting decimal (text) numbers to binary (machine) numbers is the [`strto*`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) family of functions<sup>1</sup> and, as you have probably already noticed, they require you to choose an appropriately-sized integer type for the input you expect.  Normally, when programming in C, it's possible to say that your program only needs to be able to support numbers in some fixed range, and just raise an error if you receive input outside that range.

If you truly need to support *arbitrarily large*<sup>2</sup> numbers, then you need an add-on library.  The general terms for these libraries are "bignum", "multiple precision arithmetic", and "arbitrary precision arithmetic".  One well-written, freely-licensed bignum library is [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/).

<sup>1</sup> The related `ato*` and `*scanf` functions are broken as designed - never use them for anything.  One of the ways they are broken is that they make it impossible to tell when you've received input outside the supported range.

<sup>2</sup> in absolute value, i.e. arbitrarily far away from zero in either direction

Answer (score 1):

here's my attempt , I'm working with a maximum of 64bit int (but you can change the type to whatever it is that you like) with 8 offset , meaning if you surpass 8bit (ex. 257), it'll output 16 bits , if you surpass 16 bits it'll output 24bits ... etc, I also used the first bit as the sign bit 1 for negative and 0 for positive;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <math.h>

void btd(int64_t num , char* res);
int act_size(int64_t num);
int main(void)
{
    char res[64];
    btd(-200 , res);
    printf("%s\n" , res);
}

void btd(int64_t num , char* res)
{
    int64_t tmp;
    int neg = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int64_t one_check;
    int i;

    if(num < 0)
        neg++;
    if(num < 0) 
        tmp = num * -1;
    else
        tmp = num;  
    size = act_size(tmp);
    one_check = pow(2 , size - 1); 

    printf("size %d\none flag : %ld\n" , size , one_check);

    for( i = 0 ; i < size + 1; i++)
    {
        if(!i)
        {
            if(neg)
            {
                neg = 0;
                res[0] = '1';
                num <<= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                res[0] = '0';
                num <<= 1;
            }
            continue;
        }

        if(tmp & one_check)
        {
            res[i] = '1';
            tmp <<= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            res[i] = '0';
            tmp <<= 1;
        }

    }
    res[i]  = '\0';
}

int act_size(int64_t ar)
{
    int count = 1;
    int last_one;
    int size;
    int64_t num = ar;

    if(num < 0)
        num *= -1;
    while(num)
    {
        printf("NUM : %ld\n" , num);
        if(num & 1)
        {
            last_one = count;
            num >>= 1;
        }
        else
            num >>=1;
        count++;
    }
    printf("NUM : %ld\nLAST : %d\n" , num , last_one);
    if(last_one <= 8)
        return 8;
    else if (last_one <= 16)
        return 16;
    else if (last_one <= 24)
        return 24;
    else if (last_one <= 32)
        return 32;
    else if (last_one <= 40)
        return 40;
    else if (last_one <= 48)
        return 48;
    else if (last_one <= 56)
        return 56;
    else
        return 64;
}
```

the output of this will be (since we gave it -200 as an argument)

```
NUM : 200
NUM : 100
NUM : 50
NUM : 25
NUM : 12
NUM : 6
NUM : 3
NUM : 1
NUM : 0
LAST : 8
size 8
one flag : 128
111001000
```